# is there any catalog product collection load related events in magento 2

Tags: magento2, products

I am trying to find the `catalog_product_collection_load_before` or `catalog_product_collection_load_after` events in Magento 2.
are there any relevant event handler in magento 2 to work with product collection?

Answer (score 1):

I can see the

```
catalog_product_collection_load_after
```

in `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection.php` on  `_afterLoad()` method but I can not find the `catalog_product_collection_load_before` event.

Comment: Before posting the question, I did some R&D and found, M2 did not have the catalog_product_collection_load_before event.That's why I did not accept your answer.

Comment: yes, that's what I mentioned that there is no event such as that. so this is your question to answer. @SumanSingh

Comment: @SumanSingh you mentioned catalog_product_collection_load_after also, u did not mention only catalog_product_collection_load_before event. if you asked only for before event then u have right that dont accept answer but you also asked for after event as well. Grow up